# Adapter's getItem(position) and setBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

Basically I've a View-pager where I can swipe between 1-6 pictures, using an adapter for that.

In order to "keep track" of the pictures, I implemented a selector which is represented by Image-views inflated using an adapter.

What's next, I'm using setOnPageChangeListener, more exactly the onPageSelected(int position) method to see what's the current Image-view and change its background so it can be differentiated by the rest of them. BUT this doesn't work, although it targets the proper image, the resource is not changed.

Here is some code for a better understanding:

This is where I set the size of the adapter

```
int poop = profile.getImages().size();

                for (int i = 0; i < poop; i++) {
                    ImageView image = new ImageView(v.getContext());
                    imageList.add(image);
                }

                selectorAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(imageList, (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) v.getContext());
                selector_view.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class SelectorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> mArray = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    private FragmentActivity mContext;

    public SelectorAdapter(List<ImageView> mArray, FragmentActivity mContext) {
        this.mArray = mArray;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_item, null);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Layout for the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selector_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/p_photo_unmarked"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

And finally where the magic's supposed to happen:

```
profilePic.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (selectorAdapter.getItem(position) instanceof ImageView) {
                    ((ImageView) selectorAdapter.getItem(position)).setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.p_photo_marked));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line code

```
((ImageView) selectorAdapter.getItem(position)).setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.p_photo_marked));
```

to

```
((ImageView) selectorAdapter.getItem(position)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p_photo_marked))
```

EDITED:

```
((ImageView)((SimpleTabPagerAdapter) selector_view.getAdapter()).getItem(position)).setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.p_photo_marked));
```

Comment: Try add selector_view.notifyDataSetChanged(); code into onPageSelected()

Comment: You mean selectorAdapter, which is the Adapter. I tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: I realised you got the item from your adapter (selectorAdapter). I think you should try to get from your viewPager like ((SimpleTabPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(position)

Comment: Take a look my answer again, I edited that. Try to do like that one.

Comment: That's different pictures we are talking about. I have the ViewPager that has pictures of the user and I can swipe through them and then I have this Adapter I post above that creates ImageViews on top of the User images according to how many user images I have

Comment: Hey guy, send me or post your entire code to take a look